# How to set client_flags of FOUND_ROWS in SQLAlchemy with mysqlconnector to return affected rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am trying to change the behavior of ResultProxy.rowcount attribute for SQLAlchemy.
The configuration is mysql+mysqlconnector.
I am setting connect_args = {'client_flags': [ClientFlag.FOUND_ROWS]} in the create_engine().

The problem is that it does not seem to work.
I am still getting the number of records MATCHED, rather than AFFECTED on UPDATE queries.

What is the right way to set the FOUND_ROWS client flag in SQLAlchemy?

What is the right way to get the status of the client_flags?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the other way around.

Here is what is done when the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag is set (look for FOUND_ROW in the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-connect.html))

> Return the number of found (matched) rows, not the number of changed rows.

from the [SQLAlchemy doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#rowcount-support) we see that's what they use **by default**:

> For this reason, the SQLAlchemy MySQL dialects always set the constants.CLIENT.FOUND_ROWS flag

So If you want the number of records AFFECTED on UPDATE queries, rather than MATCHED then the flag should be removed

In short, You overriding the default flag with the same flag.